# I need a way to get the content inside website urls. Many sites are not showing up in iframes due to cors issues

Tags: javascript, firebase, web-crawler

I have a URL and I need the content inside this URL. Actually, I wish to embed the content present inside this URL. What all are the possible ways to do this without any cors issues??

I have already tried using iframes and other tricks to avoid cors issues. But still, I am not able to embed many websites in an iframe. My main aim is not to embed a website in an iframe but to embed the content inside the website URL.

I will be more than happy if there is an API which returns me back the content in a URL website.
If there is not, then how can I create such an API?? And how do I get it hosted??

As a solution to this, I created a flask app which will return me the whole website so that I can embed it in my iframe. But then it is like a proxy server and I cannot host it on Heroku because Heroku does not allow public proxy server.

**Please note** embedded the whole site or just the content is of similar use to me. It is just that when embedding the site, it will be interactive and in the other case, it will not. I am good with both, embedding just the content or the whole website.

Now, I am thinking to make a web crawler which will crawl the web, cache websites and store them in a database. I am thinking to host this on firebase. I have no idea about the capabilities of the firebase. I just know that it provides us with a NoSQL database and some cloud functions.
The cloud functions part interests me.

I don't know if the following is correct/feasible.

I will send the URL(whose content I need) to firebase. It will then fetch the whole website and store it in the database(so, that next time I request the same URL, it does not need to recache the whole site again) and then return me this cached content.

If there is other better way to do this, please let me know.

I need the content for my chrome extension https://github.com/Shaikh-Ubaid/InSyd
For code, please refer to this GitHub repo.

To get an idea of why I want to get content/embed content, I am attaching a gif showing the working of the extension.

```html
<img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Shaikh-Ubaid/InSyd/master/Popup-demo.gif" alt="gif" />
```

Comment: Are you wanting to host this inside a web page (hosted in a browser)? If so I would recommend using an iFrame to host the other site. That is the simplest and most user friendly way to do it. Scraping the HTML from a page does not guarantee you can display it the way it should be displayed as most sites rely on scripts, css, and additional sever calls to display their content. If you use an iFrame there is much less of a chance you will "break" the site that you are wanting to display/host.

Comment: @Igor I am having cors issues with iframe (added this to my title as well as body). I do not understand your solution. Please elaborate. You say - "Are you wanting to host this=?? inside a web page (hosted in a browser)? If so I would recommend using an iFrame to host the other site. other site=??